Ubuntu 20.04.6 (kernel 5.4.0) - Wi-Fi Driver Intel AX211
Looking for guidance/documentation I can follow, to get wifi firmware/drivers built/backported and installed for my older kernel version.
Trying to get a very new card:
Internal Wi-Fi Antenna Intel Wi-Fi 6/6E (6GHz) AX211 2x2 Bluetooth 5.3 Wireless Card
Model: NFA76G
installed on 20.04.6 with Kernel 5.4.0.  It's a server built with ubuntu 20.04 then has ubuntu-minimal-desktop installed on it.
I've copied the available firmwares from intel here to /lib/firmware/
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
I've tried:
apt install ./backport-iwlwifi-dkms_8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.5_all.deb
apt install ./backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu3_all.deb

I get the same error for either, ... "includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arc"
I've confirmed that the wifi card works with Kernel ver 5.15.
Unfortunately I can not upgrade to latest kernel.  I've indicated what I have tried above to get drivers/firmware working on my current implementation.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, pull a gitlab repo and build it for my specific application?  What are my options beyond what I have already explored?
Thanks!

You have run into one of the risks of letting a "particular custom application" pin you down.

Thanks for the feedback, I do updates as they come in, I'm on 20.04.6.  I'm in the process of migrating to the latest LTS, meanwhile I'm looking for some near term guidance for building the wifi drivers I need to get me over the hump.
My question is more related to the options for backporting drivers.

thanks, updated!

FYI:  If you're planning on upgrading to a later release as your comment states; the effort related to changing kernel modules makes little sense to me; as 5.4 (what you're using now & asking to change) relates to 20.04 only; where 22.04 or jammy uses the 5.15 kernel as its GA kernel stack (so you're planning on repeating this???), and 24.04 or the latest LTS uses 6.8 (though also note upgrades to 24.04 LTS from 22.04 won't open until after 15 August 2024 as stated in release notes for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)   You can switch to the 5.15 kernel now (which may accomplish what you want)

At the risk of making some of the responses out of context with my question, I've updated the question tailored more specifically to what I'm looking for.  I greatly appreciate the feedback and the time you have afforded me with responses thus far!

Have you fixed the problem?
If not yet, please follow these steps I just completed:

Download backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu6_all.deb to save somewhere on your drive
Restart to BIOS and turn off secure boot
At the place you saved the downloaded file, open a terminal
Run sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu6_all.deb
Restart
Enjoy your WiFi

